# AngularJS reset form completely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a pretty big form that's being validated on the client side by Angular. I am trying to figure out how to reset the state of the form and its inputs just clicking on a Reset button.

I have tried `$setPristine()` on the form but it didn't really work, meaning that it doesn't clear the `ng-*` classes to reset the form to its original state with no validation performed.

Here's a short version of my form:

```
<form id="create" name="create" ng-submit="submitCreateForm()" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input required type="text" ng-model="project.name" name="name" class="form-control">
            <div ng-show="create.$submitted || create.name.$touched">
                <span class="help-block" ng-show="create.name.$error.required">Name is required</span>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input required type="text" ng-model="project.lastName" name="lastName" class="form-control">
            <div ng-show="create.$submitted || create.lastName.$touched">
                <span class="help-block" ng-show="create.lastName.$error.required">Last name is required</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="resetProject()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

And my reset function:

```
$scope.resetProject = function() {
    $scope.project = {
        state: "finished",
        topic: "Home automation"
    };
    $("#create input[type='email']").val('');
    $("#create input[type='date']").val('');
    $scope.selectedState = $scope.project.state;
    // $scope.create.$setPristine(); // doesn't work
}
```

Also if you could help me clear the input values of the email and date fields without using jQuery would be great. Because setting the `$scope.project` to what's defined above doesn't reset the fields for some reason.

Comment: What does "it really didn't work" mean?.

Comment: Also it would be useful to get a plnkr showing your issue.

Comment: it doesn't clear the `ng-*` classes to reset the form to its original state with no validation performed

Comment: You tried `$scope.create.$setUntouched();` - depending on the version you're using.

Comment: @Darren you're a genius that's exactly what I wanted. I guess I messed that functionality to what `$setPristine()` does. Post as answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: and also, I'd be very happy if anyone could help me out with those jQuery needed calls

Comment: @dabadaba - no worries, glad i could help :)

Comment: Ref the jquery - you should never interact with the DOM via controllers. That's what the directives are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `$setUntouched();`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setUntouched

This should set the form back to it's new state.

So in this case `$scope.create.$setUntouched();` should do the trick

Ref all that jquery. You should never interact with the DOM via controllers. That's what the directives are for

If you want to reset a given property then do something like:

```
$scope.resetProject = function() {
    $scope.project = {
        state: "finished",
        topic: "Home automation"
    };
    $scope.project.lastName = '';
   $scope.project.date= '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear via ng-model

```
$scope.resetProject = function() {
  $scope.project = {
      state: "finished",
      topic: "Home automation"
  };
  $("#create input[type='email']").val('');
  $("#create input[type='date']").val('');
  $scope.selectedState = $scope.project.state;

  $scope.project = {
      name: "",
      lastName: ""
  };
}
```